# Netty channelRead

Tags: scala, netty

I have started working with Netty and have a question.  I am bootstrapping Netty as shown in the examples.

```
def connect {
  try {
    bootstrap.group(group)
             .channel(classOf[NioSocketChannel])
             .remoteAddress(new InetSocketAddress(host, port))
             .handler(new ChannelInitializer[SocketChannel] {
               override def initChannel(ch: SocketChannel) {
                 ch.pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8))
                            .addLast(new NettyConnectionChannelInbound)
               }
             })

    val future: ChannelFuture = bootstrap.connect.sync

    future.channel.closeFuture.sync
  } finally {
    group.shutdownGracefully
  }
}
```

I have another class with the channelRead method in it

```
class NettyConnectionChannelInbound extends ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter {
  override def channelRead(ctx: ChannelHandlerContext, msg: Any) {
    println(msg)
  }
}
```

When I run my application

```
val nc = new NettyConnection
nc.connect
println("After connection")
```

It doesn't ever seem to get to the println after the connect call.  Is this expected or am I doing something wrong?  Does it just sit and wait for incoming messages to come in if I don't close the socket after receiving something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is because closeFuture().sync() will block until the channel is closed. So I don't think this is what you want...

Comment: Thank you.  That makes sense now that you point that out.  I had just taken the example given on the Netty site and didn't think about the fact that I was blocking there until the channel closed.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are using netty python. But it seems somewhat strange to me that your bootstrap.connect does not specify host & port...(could that be due to pseudo-code grabbed from online)

Of course it needs to be blocking after connection otherwise your program would quit with connection being forced to close.

Your channelRead will not be invoked until a message is sent from the other end of the network.